# AngularJS - listener in service

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, angular-services

Can you listen for "any" calls to a service within the service itself in order to verify some other condition before executing on the service?

I have this:

```
.factory('socket',function('socketFactory') {

      var socket = io.connect(nodeUrl, {
        query: my_query
      });

      return socket;
});
```

Within socketFactory are many methods such as `emit`, `connect`, and more, as well as properties such as `connected`.

In my controllers, I inject the `socket` factory and do simple stuff like:

`socket.emit("test_message");`

What I want to do is check the `connected` property simply within the `socket` service before executing any of the methods. If the server went down, for example, then `socket.connected=false` and I would want to know that I need to reinitialize the  connection.

I could manually put all the methods in the service with `if(socket.connected) { ... }` but am wondering if it can be done simply with one block for all methods in socketFactory.

I'm really looking for something like this (which does not work):

```
  socket.on(event, function(){
    console.log("You tried:" + event);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two questions in the OP, I will answer the first:

```
.factory('socket',function('socketFactory') {
  var socket = {};
  socket._socket = { connected: false };
  socket.initialize = function() {
    this._socket = io.connect(nodeUrl, {
      query: my_query
    });
  };
  socket.initialize();
  // find all available functions on socket._socket
  var fns = Object.keys(socket._socket).filter(function (x) {
    return typeof socket._socket[x] == 'function';
  });
  // create a one-to-one mapping of functions on socket from the
  // member _socket such that we check the socket connection state
  // before calling the underlying _socket function with the same 
  // name
  angular.forEach(fns, function (x) {
    socket[x] = function () {
      if (!this._socket.connected) {
        this.initialize();
      } 
      if (this._socket.connected) {
        this._socket[x].apply(this._socket, [].slice.call(arguments));
      }
    }
  });

  return socket;
});
```